# coredump redirect to file

Tags: c, linux, makefile, coredump

I am invoking make from my C program, which intern executes another program. I am redirecting both the standard out and standard error to a file. However, when the program run by make terminates due to segmentation fault, a core dump is generated and printed to the console (standard out) of the main program that is invoking make.

How can I get around this and not have the core dump show on the console?

The following is my code to invoke make :

```
 int pid = fork();

 if(pid==0){
 dup2(make_logs, 1);
 dup2(make_logs, 2);
 close(make_logs);
 execvp (args[0],args);
 }
```

Where make_logs is the file opened using 'open'

Thanks

Comment: Please confirm that running the program (or any other program) from the command lines does not have the same problem.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that if the same program is run , there is the core dump. However, what I dont understand is since both the standard out and error are being redirected, this should be written to the file and not propogated upto the parent process..

Comment: if you run your program here with `strace -f`, you'll see all the syscalls of the processes and see what and how things get propagated.

Comment: Show the value of `args`... Is it properly `NULL` terminated?

Comment: The `core` file is probably *not* dumped to *stdout* (it is a big sparse binary file). Perhaps you get a textual message "core dumped" which is given by some shell (or by `make`).

Comment: Explain much more what your `make` is doing (perhaps by showing relevant portions of your `Makefile`), and which program is crashing with a `core` dump.

Comment: I am just interested in a way to not have the backtrace and memory map which is being printed out of a child process in the terminal when that processes suffers from a seg fault... I am not interested in fixing the issue, as the behaviour is expected with regards to my application as I am performing fault injection

Answer (score 1):

I would try to fix the core dump rather than suppressing the message, but the message about the segmentation fault is being generated by the shell (which detects the exit value of the child and recognize a core dump situation), so you can suppress it by installing your own program that handles the fork() and wait() rather than having the shell do the work.

To suppress the core dump, just use limit coredumpsize 0.

Sample of suppression (sloppy code; you should really be checking for errors):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int pid;
    if( (pid = fork() ) > 0 ) wait( 0 );
    else if( pid == 0 ) {
        execl( "program-that-cdumps", "program-that-cdumps", 0 );
        perror("failed in execl");
    } else perror("failed in fork");
}
```

Comment: Hi, how can I handle it in fork() wait() rather than limiting the size?

Comment: Problem still persists, I get the following in the terminal which I do not want:

http://pastebin.com/V2yywTmW

Answer (score 0):

Read [core(5)](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) and [signal(7)](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) man pages.

Compile all your programs with `gcc -Wall -g`. Then use

```
file core
```

to understand which binary dumped the core. It probably says something like `core dump from foo` to tell you that program `foo` dumped the core. Then, start a post mortem debugger on it:

```
gdb foo core
```

and use the common `gdb` commands (notably `bt` to backtrace, `p` to print, etc...).

The message `dumped core` is given by some shell (or perhaps by `make` when it is acting like a shell). I don't think that the `core` file is output to `stdout` (it is a big binary file).

If you wish to avoid the `core` (which IMHO is a bad idea, a `core` dump is a good symptom of something wrong), you could call the [setrlimit(2)](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) syscall with `RLIMIT_CORE` and a 0 limit after your `fork` and before the `execvp`. I believe you should not do that (or at least have some way of configuring that `setrlimit` is not called: sometimes you really need the `core` dump to debug the problem).

You should fix the problem which gives the `core` dump, not try to avoid the `dumped core` message!

If you run `make` on a *user provided* `Makefile` so that the `core` dump is from a user program, you really want to keep the user informed that a `core` did happen, so you should keep the `core dumped` message.

Comment: I am just interested in a way to not have the backtrace and memory map which is being printed out of a child process in the terminal when that processes suffers from a seg fault... I am not interested in fixing the issue, as the behaviour is expected with regards to my application as I am performing fault injection